# How do I properly add a theme region to a views-view--page.tpl.php in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

OK, so here is what I have and found (which works - however it produces a log Notice) "***Only variables should be passed by reference in eval()***" which is driving me absolutely crazy!

Initially like any theme region I added the regions I wanted for views use to the theme.info file.

```
; View Regions
regions[view_header]    = View Header
regions[view_content]   = View Content
regions[view_footer]    = View Footer
```

In the views-view--page.tpl.php I placed these (where I wanted the region to render)

```
<?php print render(block_get_blocks_by_region('view_header')); ?>
<?php print render(block_get_blocks_by_region('view_content')); ?>
<?php print render(block_get_blocks_by_region('view_footer')); ?>
```

This produces a notice for each entry in the tpl yet it works as expected 100%

I then tried adding a hook in the themes template.php (in an attempt to make variables out of them) so I can just use `<?php print $view_header; ?>` like so:

```
function theme_preprocess_views_view(&$variables){
  $variables['view_header'] = render(block_get_blocks_by_region('view_header'));
  $variables['view_content'] = render(block_get_blocks_by_region('view_content'));
  $variables['view_footer'] = render(block_get_blocks_by_region('view_footer'));
```

Again this works - and again this produces log notices.. this time 3 for each region on all page loads, so 9 instead of 3 (not just when the views-view--page.tpl.php loads) which traced back to theme template.php (same notice as listed above this time but no notice from the $variables used in the views template when that page loads).

Obviously I'm missing something here! Maybe this is entirely the wrong way to do this...

How do I make the theme regions usable variables in tpl's?

- I'm under the impression everything I've found is years old (3 to 10) and likely worked fine for php 5.x - this site is currently using php 7.2.x (should that make a difference in how this needs to be done)

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the function [`render()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/7.x/includes/common.inc#L6244) expects a reference, and *only variables should be passed by reference* :

```
function render(&$element) {
  # code need to be able to modify $element
}

render('value');                                   # throws notice
render(block_get_blocks_by_region('view_header')); # throws notice

$value = 'value';
$build = block_get_blocks_by_region('view_header');
render($value); # Ok
render($build); # Ok
```

Also, I think the way to go should be to assign the renderable arrays to `$variables` in the preprocess hook :

```
function theme_preprocess_views_view(&$variables){
  $variables['view_header'] = block_get_blocks_by_region('view_header');
  $variables['view_content'] = block_get_blocks_by_region('view_content');
  $variables['view_footer'] = block_get_blocks_by_region('view_footer');
  # ...
}
```

... and let the template call `render()` :

```
<?php print render($view_header); ?>
<?php print render($view_content); ?>
<?php print render($view_footer); ?>
```

Comment: Yup... that did it! I knew the reason for the warning/notice, just wasn't familiar with how to get the blocks into variables properly to pass to the views tpl. I think at one point in the themes template.php I actually had tried the exact code block you provided but at the time got no results, not even a notice/warning. Most likely because I forgot to clear cache or didn't save the tpl with via nano after I added the print render(s). There was a moment I was just flailing to make it work trying everything I could think of (usually where typos, not clearing cache and or saving files after edit)

Comment: Thank you kindly... my logs are now empty!